Generalized chain rule for multivariable functions
Let x(t) = $(x_1(t),\dots,x_m(t))$ and let $f: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}$ be a multivariable function. Then let $\hat f$(t) = f (x(t)).
I know that $$\frac{d\hat f(t)}{dt} = \sum_{h=1}^m \frac{\partial f(x(t))}{\partial x_h} \frac{dx_h(t)}{dt}$$
Now let y(x(t)) = $(y_1(x(t)),\dots,y_l(x(t)))$ and $g: \mathbb{R}^l \to \mathbb{R}$. Again, let $\hat g$(t) = g (y(x(t))).
Intuition suggests that
$$\frac{d\hat g(t)}{dt} = \sum_{h=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^l \frac{\partial g(y(x(t)))}{\partial y_j} \frac{\partial y_j(x(t))}{\partial x_h}\frac{dx_h(t)}{dt}$$
Is this kind of multivariable, "multi composite" chain rule true? If so, could you please sketch a proof or tell me where I may look for one? Thanks in advance.

The general chain rule is $D(f \circ g)(x) = Df(g(x))Dg(x)$, where $Dg(x)$ is the Frechet derivative of $g(x)$. In coordinates, $Dg(x)$ is the Jacobian matrix.

Is the double sum correct?

Yes it is correct

Thank you. Could you please write explicitly how to obtain it from what you wrote before?

Do the matrix multiplication. Like $(ABC){ij} = \sum{k,\ell}a_{ik}b_{k\ell}c_{\ell j}$.

Thank you very much

Sorry to write again, but I am not sure about what the matrices A, B, C are, since you wrote a formula which only involves two matrices in your first comment

For you, $D\hat{g}(t) = Dg(y(x(t)))Dy(x(t))Dx(t)$.
